# Unable to Edit Categories via Channel Entry

Tags: channel-entries, categories

I'm unable to Edit Categories under the Categories tab of a Channel Entry view. When I click on Edit Categories nothing happens. Looking at Console this is the error it produces:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined
```

I've been using EE for four years and have never had this issue. Any thoughts?

Using EE 2.8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like this is a known js error - maybe patch here will work?  https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20237